# How to disable the "Log in to iCloud" nag when logging in to computer lab workstations?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Every time a user logs in to a computer lab workstation running Mac OS 10.7, the "Log in to iCloud" nag screen tries to show itself, but since permission for that System Preferences pane is disabled, they just get an error message.  Since the pane never shows itself, this happens again next time the user logs in.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE
```